Error: node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:72:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type
I got this error since I upgraded Angular from 14 to 15, I tried to update typescript from "^4.8.2" to "^4.9.3" so that I can upgrade angular from 15 to 16 but when I tried to update typescript I got following dependencies errors:
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-eslint/schematics@14.0.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cli@15.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/cli@"~15.2.11" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cli@">= 14.0.0 < 15.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@14.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!   dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"14.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/cli@14.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cli@">= 14.0.0 < 15.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@14.0.2        
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"14.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried this two commands
nmp update --force

npm i typescript@4.9.3

How to fix the above dependencies errors to avoid the error below, please?
    Error: node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:72:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  
    Variable 'AbortSignal' must be of type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal; 
    timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; }', but here has type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; }'.

72 declare var AbortSignal: {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2071:13
    2071 declare var AbortSignal: {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'AbortSignal' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts (lines 72-76)
declare var AbortSignal: {
    prototype: AbortSignal;
    new(): AbortSignal;
    // TODO: Add abort() static
};

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts (lines 2071-2076)
declare var AbortSignal: {
    prototype: AbortSignal;
    new(): AbortSignal;
    abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal;
    timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal;
};

package.json
Package                                 Current   Wanted   Latest  Location                                             Depended by
@angular-devkit/build-angular           15.2.11  15.2.11   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular           ...  
@angular-eslint/builder                  14.0.2   14.0.2   17.3.0  node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder                 ...  
@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin            14.0.2   14.0.2   17.3.0  node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin           ...  
@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template   14.0.2   14.0.2   17.3.0  node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template  ...  
@angular-eslint/schematics               14.0.2   14.0.2   17.3.0  node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics              ...  
@angular-eslint/template-parser          14.0.2   14.0.2   17.3.0  node_modules/@angular-eslint/template-parser         ...  
@angular/animations                     15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/animations                     ...  
@angular/cli                            15.2.11  15.2.11   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/cli                            ...  
@angular/common                         15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/common                         ...  
@angular/compiler                       15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/compiler                       ...  
@angular/compiler-cli                   15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli                   ...  
@angular/core                           15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/core                           ...  
@angular/forms                          15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/forms                          ...
@angular/localize                       15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/localize                       ...
@angular/platform-browser               15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser               ...
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic       15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic       ...
@angular/platform-server                15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/platform-server                ...
@angular/router                         15.2.10  15.2.10   17.3.6  node_modules/@angular/router                         ...
@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome         0.11.1   0.11.1   0.14.1  node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome        ...
@ngx-translate/core                      14.0.0   14.0.0   15.0.0  node_modules/@ngx-translate/core                     ...
@ngx-translate/http-loader                7.0.0    7.0.0    8.0.0  node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader              ...
@progress/kendo-angular-buttons           8.2.2    8.2.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons         ...
@progress/kendo-angular-common            3.2.2    3.2.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-common          ...
@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs        7.1.6    7.1.6   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs      ...
@progress/kendo-angular-dialog            7.1.5    7.1.5   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dialog          ...
@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns         7.2.4    7.2.4   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns       ...
@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export      5.0.2    5.0.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export    ...
@progress/kendo-angular-grid              7.4.2    7.4.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid            ...
@progress/kendo-angular-icons             2.0.3    2.0.3   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-icons           ...
@progress/kendo-angular-indicators        2.0.0    2.0.0   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-indicators      ...
@progress/kendo-angular-inputs            9.0.5    9.0.5   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs          ...
@progress/kendo-angular-intl              4.1.1    4.1.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl            ...
@progress/kendo-angular-l10n              4.0.1    4.0.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-l10n            ...
@progress/kendo-angular-label             4.0.2    4.0.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-label           ...
@progress/kendo-angular-layout            7.2.0    7.2.0   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-layout          ...
@progress/kendo-angular-listview          4.0.4    4.0.4   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-listview        ...
@progress/kendo-angular-menu              4.1.1    4.1.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-menu            ...
@progress/kendo-angular-navigation        2.1.1    2.1.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-navigation      ...
@progress/kendo-angular-notification      4.0.1    4.0.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-notification    ...
@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export        4.0.1    4.0.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export      ...
@progress/kendo-angular-popup             5.0.2    5.0.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup           ...
@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar       3.1.2    3.1.2   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar     ...
@progress/kendo-angular-ripple            4.0.1    4.0.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-ripple          ...
@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip           4.1.1    4.1.1   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip         ...
@progress/kendo-angular-treeview          7.1.5    7.1.5   15.5.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-treeview        ...
@progress/kendo-svg-icons                 0.1.2    0.1.2    2.3.0  node_modules/@progress/kendo-svg-icons               ...
@progress/kendo-theme-default            5.12.0   5.12.0    7.2.1  node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default           ...
@types/jasmine                            4.0.3    4.0.3    5.1.4  node_modules/@types/jasmine                          ...
@types/node                             17.0.45  17.0.45  20.12.7  node_modules/@types/node                             ...
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin         5.29.0   5.29.0    7.8.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin        ...
@typescript-eslint/parser                5.29.0   5.29.0    7.8.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser               ...
angular-oauth2-oidc                      14.0.1   14.0.1   17.0.2  node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc                     ...
cldr-core                                42.0.0   42.0.0   45.0.0  node_modules/cldr-core                               ...
cldr-dates-full                          42.0.0   42.0.0   45.0.0  node_modules/cldr-dates-full                         ...
cldr-numbers-full                        42.0.0   42.0.0   45.0.0  node_modules/cldr-numbers-full                       ...
eslint                                   8.57.0   8.57.0    9.1.1  node_modules/eslint                                  ...
jasmine-core                              4.1.1    4.1.1    5.1.2  node_modules/jasmine-core                            ...
karma                                    6.3.20   6.3.20    6.4.3  node_modules/karma                                   ...
karma-chrome-launcher                     3.1.1    3.1.1    3.2.0  node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher                   ...
karma-jasmine                             5.0.1    5.0.1    5.1.0  node_modules/karma-jasmine                           ...
karma-jasmine-html-reporter               1.7.0    1.7.0    2.1.0  node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter             ...
ngx-translate-testing                     6.1.0    6.1.0    7.0.0  node_modules/ngx-translate-testing                   ...
rxjs                                      7.5.7    7.5.7    7.8.1  node_modules/rxjs                                    ...
typescript                                4.9.5    4.9.5    5.4.5  node_modules/typescript                              ...
zone.js                                  0.11.8   0.11.8   0.14.4  node_modules/zone.js                                 ...


Could it be that you didn't update the angular-eslint/schematics package to a version compatible with Angular 15 ?
From what you are showing, it seems to me that the angular-eslint/schematics is still on version 14.0.2, I would advise you to update it to the latest 15.x.x version and then see if the problems persists.

I tried the different versions npm i @angular-eslint/schematics@15.X.X but I always got other dependencies errors. I edited the question to add the result of the command npm outdated.

How about using the angular CLI for the update :
ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@15

It worked, thank you, the error is gone and the application is running with angular 15.

I'll add a more detailed answer so you can close the question.

When you ran ng update to upgrade your Angular project on version 15, you probably encountered an error that led you to use the --force option.
This installed Angular 15 but ignored the version discrepancy with angular-eslint.
This can then be fixed by updating angular-eslint using the angular cli.
ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@15

